Will the Azure App continue working when changing the publisher name?
I have a question regarding changing the publisher name of an already published app in Microsoft Azure, under the App registration menu.
The app is one that users give consent to (similar to logging in with Outlook). On the partner canter, it says that the app will be reviewed after changing the Publisher name.
The questions I have are:

Does changing the Publisher Name and saving the change break the
existing app until the new Publisher name is approved?
What happens to new users during the review period? Will they be able to see the old published name and use the app?
What happens to old/existing users who have given consent to the app & its scopes? Will they have to re-auth after the publisher name change is approved?

Thanks in advance
